# Flutter widget: How can I make a Calendar widget where user drags the date range with finger?

Tags: flutter, date, datepicker, calendar, widget

Title says it all. I am able to use multiple calendar widgets in Flutter but none of them seem to support the user using a "dragging" gesture to select the dates.

How would one design this, possibly with some sort of Gesture control?

Comment: Just so we are on the same page, the showDateRangePicker() does not work out for you?